# Javascript смена URL на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть URL, которые проставляют на странице пользователи.
Допустим это example.com/blabla/bla/bla/1.html ( после example.com может быть что угодно. )
Этот URL есть где-то в коде страницы.
Нужно его менять на http://test.com?=http://example.com... и продолжение запроса. образно говоря "подставлять" перед -другой URL.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно как-то отделять эти урл от остальных на сайте, например, давая им специальный класс или дописывая другой атрибут. Ну а дальше все просто: пройдитесь по ним и допишите в href нужную вам информацию:

```
$('.your-class').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://test.com?url=' + $(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).removeClass('your-class');
});
```